# Why always use 32 bit registry for check for installed .NET version?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

From the Microsoft example code at [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx#net_c), when querying for the installed version of .NET for 4.5 or later, they are using the following code to get to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full

```
const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";
using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey
    .OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
{
    //The rest of their example code
}
```

My question is: Why do they do it this way (always `RegistryView.Registry32`), with no note as to why they do not at least open the key selectively based on the system the code is running on?

The appropriate values on my workstation do exist in the 64 bit location and also within the WOW6432Node\ location, so I've just been assuming that both locations will be written on 64 bit machines, and the 32 bit view will be used on a 32 bit machine, so reading the 32 bit location should be considered "safe". However, this is just an assumption of mine that I haven't been able to confirm, as I've seen no mention of it so far. And I don't want to use this example code in my production code if my assumption is incorrect.